# Updates don't work in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, 13.10

Hello guys I hope you're all fine. This is the problem: When I execute the updater it always throws the same error saying: Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection. 
And when I run the `sudo apt-get update` I get these lines at the end:

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release i386 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release i386 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to remove the 2 cdrom entries. You can remove them by either manually editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` or using the `Software Sources` utility.

The PPA errors are likely because the tiheum/equinox ppa is not updated to include packages for 13.10 saucy yet. The safest way to remove it is:

- `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`
- `ppa-purge tiheum/equinox`

Assuming you want to remove the ppa (if you don't remember adding it or what it provides, you should remove it).